# how to join two (or more) columns recorded in separate files?

Tags: sed, cut

I have this two files (file1.txt and file2.txt) my wanted output is output12.txt:

file1.txt

```
1c 2c
1c 2c
```

file2.txt

```
1c 2c
1c 2c
```

output12.txt

```
1c 2c
1c 2c
1c 2c
1c 2c
```

how i can do this ? sed pipe cut ?

Comment: does appending the files together not work?

Comment: please provide a less ambiguous example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just append the content of `file2.txt` after the content of `file1.txt` and the result is another file (named `output12.txt`), then you can try the following:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > output12.txt
```